# How can I make graph using matplotlib with json (or yaml) files?

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

I am dealing with some struggles making a script, which could make a graph with inputs from yaml or json files. Firstly, I tried it with yaml files, but failed - now I have my yaml files converted into json files and trying it with them.

And what particular I want to?

I have 400+ json files containing specific information about specific structure (there are 400+ structures, thus there are 400+ json files). I am interested in one data from json files and it is 'Resolution': 0.00 (it is some float), because I want to know how many of the structures have what resolution (so, x axis should be resolution values which are occured in structures and y axis should be amount of structures, which have this resolution.

I have never used matplotlib before, so I am failing right at the beginning of script, defining x and y axis and how to implement information from json file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json

#this is preparation for my inputs, nothing important for my current question
cif_ID = "aaa, bbb" #there are 400+ IDs
cif_input = cif_ID.split(", ")
for ID in cif_input:
json_path = "/home/ME/something/something/{}/" .format(ID) 
json_file = json_path + "{}.json" .format(ID)


with open(json_file, "r") as f:
    doc = json.load(f)

    resolution = doc['Resolution']
    print(resolution)  #this print me all resolution values (float) from all 400+ json files

    x = (doc['Resolution']) #I know this is wrong way, but I want to just show that I tried
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of one JSON file?

Comment: I'm a little bit at loss what exactly does not work or what your question is. What is the significance of the files being JSON or YAML? What does "specific information about specific structure" mean? And is that relevant for the question? 
Please explain more clearly what you want to accomplish and where the problem is.

Comment: I have never used matplotlib before, thus I dont know if it is significant that files are json(or yaml), because I dont know if it is usual way of building graphs from data in those files. I posted below an example of my json file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggested json file format here is the sample code. this code will first generate sample json files in './data' directory and then it will read sample resolution values from those files.

```
import os
import json
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

master_data_dir = './data'
os.makedirs(master_data_dir,exist_ok = True)

# +++++++++++++++++++++++++
# generate json file
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++

# some JSON Format in file:
# x1 =  '{ "x":"J", "Resolution":17, "y":"51"}'
# x2 =  '{ "x":"J", "Resolution":11, "y":"52"}'
# x3 =  '{ "x":"J", "Resolution":10, "y":"53"}'

x1 =  { "x":"J1", "Resolution":17, "y":"51"}
x2 =  { "x":"J2", "Resolution":11, "y":"52"}
x3 =  { "x":"J3", "Resolution":10, "y":"53"}
x4 =  { "x":"J4", "Resolution":10, "y":"54"}
x5 =  { "x":"J5", "Resolution":10, "y":"55"}
x6 =  { "x":"J6", "Resolution":11, "y":"56"}
x7 =  { "x":"J7", "Resolution":13, "y":"57"}
x8 =  { "x":"J8", "Resolution":15, "y":"58"}
x9 =  { "x":"J9", "Resolution":17, "y":"59"}
x10 =  { "x":"J10", "Resolution":15, "y":"60"}

filename = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10']

for i,j in enumerate([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10]):
    with open(master_data_dir+'/'+filename[i]+".json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(j,f)
        f.close()
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Ends here
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Read json data to findout resolution frequency
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

list_files_in_data_dir  = os.listdir(master_data_dir)
resoltuion_values = [] 
for json_file_name in list_files_in_data_dir:
    json_file_path =  os.path.join(master_data_dir,json_file_name)
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
        jsondata = json.load(f)
        resoltuion_values.append(jsondata['Resolution'])
        f.close()


resoltuion_values =  np.array(resoltuion_values)
unique_resolutions, frequency = np.unique(resoltuion_values, return_counts=True) 
print("Unique Resolution : " , unique_resolutions)
print("Frequency Count : ", frequency)

plt.bar(unique_resolutions,frequency) 
plt.title("unique_resolutions vs frequency Plot") 
plt.xticks(unique_resolutions, fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('Unique Resolutions', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[Ouput of this code is a bar plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnRzG.png)
Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any query.

Comment: This is example of what is in my json files:   {"DOI or PMID": "10.1038/35101544", "L22_chain": "L", "L4_chain": "K", "Method": "X-ray diffraction", "Organism": "Deinococcus radiodurans", "Resolution": 3.5, "Title": "STRUCTURAL BASIS FOR THE INTERACTION OF ANTIBIOTICS WITH THE PEPTIDYL TRANSFERASE CENTER IN EUBACTERIA"}

Comment: I have hundreds of similar files, each file corresponds to specific molecular structure. Thus, resolution values usually differ (in some structures are same, in some are very diferent) and I want to make a graph/histogram, where at "x" axis would be all occuring resolution values and at "y" axis would be amount of the structures, which have that resolution value